# Copy row to new sheet if numeric value in column differs from row to row (every two rows compared)

Tags: excel

I have two tables combined where in every ODD numbered row (1, 3, 5....633), it contains the values of my MAIN table (that's in red in my attached screenshot).

The EVEN rows are from a USER table that needs to be updated (that's in blue in my screenshot).

The numeric string that's in column B is the key value that I'm using for my comparative value. For every numeric value in the ODD row that is different to the one beneath it in the EVEN row, I want that ODD row (in Red) copied to a new sheet. If you notice that column A is a repeating numeric value for every TWO rows (that's a loan number and that record needs to be updated with those numeric values that are different in Column B)....this will be the project once all the differentiating rows are identified.

For instance, in the screenshot, row #359, 361, 363, etc., would be copied to a new sheet because the value in Column B in the even row beneath it is different

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to do this manually, with formulas, VBA? If you're familiar with VBA, I'd suggest using the macro recorder in the following way:

1. add a formula to check the odd/even values `=OR(B1=B2,MOD(ROW(),2)=0)` (this formula will only return `FALSE` on ODD rows where the value of the row below differs)
2. filter on `FALSE`
3. select the visible (filtered) cells
4. copy and paste the cells into the new sheet

I hope this helps. Let us know what works!